# How do I resolve the Node permission error?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install all my project's dependencies using `npm install` but I get the following error

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\caio_\Desktop\goodfellas\monorepo\node_modules\.bin\goodfellas-api-server
npm ERR! errno -4092
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat 'C:\Users\caio_\Desktop\goodfellas\monorepo\node_modules\.bin\goodfellas-api-server'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat 'C:\Users\caio_\Desktop\goodfellas\monorepo\node_modules\.bin\goodfellas-api-server'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4092,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\caio_\\Desktop\\goodfellas\\monorepo\\node_modules\\.bin\\goodfellas-api-server'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\caio_\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-16T23_05_02_968Z-debug-0.log
```

Would you help me? I'm using WINDOWS 11, and node 18.15.0

I tried to use this command in PowerShell as an administrator, but I got no result.

Comment: Never use admin for npm. Delete your entire `node_modules` directory, then rerun `npm install` using a normal cmd/powershell/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like file permission issue or an antivirus software blocking file access.

Clear npm cache `npm cache clean --force`

If you are using an antivirus software that can block file access. Try again after disabling it.